# Encrypted password is different after using role-based Enum on User object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, encryption

I was creating a user login that works perfectly fine during registration. When the user fills out the Sign Up form and submits it, it logs the user into their account as intended. But when I log out and attempt to log in again using the Login Form, it won't authenticate the user, even though the credentials are indeed correct.

My app has three different types of user roles: *player*, *owner*, and *admin*. I believe that it has something to do with when I persist the role to the user during registration, which is causing the authentication on Login to not work.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Roles
  enum role: [:player => 0, :owner => 1, :admin => 2]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  # Validations
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  # validates_confirmation_of :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  attr_accessor :password_confirmation, :role_type

  def set_default_role
      self.role ||= :player
  end

  def encrypt_password
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, self.password_salt)
  end

  def self.authenticate(username, password)
      user = User.where(username: username).first

      if user && user.password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
          return user
      else
          return nil
      end
  end
end
```

---

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper

  before_filter :current_user

  def index
    @user = User.new
  end

  # Display the SignUp Form
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    # Save to the database
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome, #{@user.username}!"
        session[:user_id] = @user.id

        # Check if they selected Owner checkbox
        if user_params[:role_type].to_i == 1
            @user.owner!
        else
            @user.player!
        end

        redirect_accordingly(@user)
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Some of the info you provided needs tweaking."
        render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :role_type)
  end
end
```

---

**sessions_controller.rb** -- where Login is handled

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
include ApplicationHelper

#Login Process
def create

    # authenticate method returns nil when a role is 
    # persisted to the user during registration
    # e.g. when @user.owner! is used in the UsersController#create

    if @user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{@user.username}!"
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_accordingly(@user)
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid username or password. #{@user}"
        render :new
    end
end

#Login Form
def new
    @user = User.new
end

#Log Out
def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You have logged out."
end
end
```

In UsersController#create, the conditional `if` statement persists a role to the user during registration such as `@user.owner!` or `@user.player!` which works because it adds the correct integer to the database's `role` column, and logs the new user in.

After I log out, I attempt to use the Login Form to log the user back in again, but it does not succeed. The `User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])` method returns `nil`. So I began to dissect the method in the rails console:

Let's say I have this in my database for example:

```
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id | username     | password                                                     | password_salt                 | email                   | created_at          | updated_at          | role |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 27 | grahamsutt12 | $2a$10$T6cRC/F0NQOeHhorQfxLjOkVQfOPwvUU0eEbKhlS.Pa4aD2TRvxvy | $2a$10$T6cRC/F0NQOeHhorQfxLjO | graham@gmail.com        | 2015-05-22 01:19:24 | 2015-05-22 01:19:24 |    0 |
| 28 | mike12       | $2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv.VIJzaGetvnB88kt/IzCEuFK1JgZBzBO | $2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv. | mike@gmail.com          | 2015-05-22 02:07:33 | 2015-05-22 02:07:33 |    1 |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+

#password for mike12 is "mikerton"

# Returns incorrectly
User.authenticate("mike12", "mikerton") 
User Load (59.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'mike12'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil 

### Now, diving in to the authenticate method ###

# Returns correctly
user = User.where(username: "mike12").first
User Load (56.9ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'mike12'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 28, username: "mike12", password: "$2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv.VIJzaGetvnB88kt/IzCEu...", password_salt: "$2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv.", email: "mike@gmail.com", created_at: "2015-05-22 02:07:33", updated_at: "2015-05-22 02:07:33", role: 1>


#!!! Passwords are different from each other? !!!#
BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("mikerton", user.password_salt)
=> "$2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv.rus89JjBDd2Mna6aRD8xgkMEO3FEPzK"

user.password
=> "$2a$10$S7vOdf43uhMU0/RUOc/vv.VIJzaGetvnB88kt/IzCEuFK1JgZBzBO"
```

As you can see the password are different after the `vv.` in both encryptions.

Additionally, I should add that the encryptions are the **same** when I do *not* use `@user.owner` or `@user.player` during SignUp, but the user's role comes out to `1`.

Why is this altering the password encryptions and how can I store roles in the database the properly with the "Rails way" using `enum`?

Answer (score 2):

So the way I've done it is as follows:

In my model, define my enum:

```
enum role: [:player => 0, :owner => 1, :admin => 2]
```

Then in my user form, define the role:

```
<%= f.label :role, "Account Type", class: "label-hidden" %>
<%= f.select :role, options_for_user_role %>
```

Then in my users helper, I've defined the options. Basically, you need to send in a string and not an integer.

```
def options_for_user_role
 [
   ['Select Account Type', ' '],
   ['Player','player'],
   ['Owner','owner']
 ]
end
```

Then in your controller, make sure to add role to your permitted params

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :role)
end
```

Then in your users controller create method, you don't need to have the code checking if the role_type was 1 or 0, you could just remove it (don't need this):

```
# Check if they selected Owner checkbox
    if user_params[:role_type].to_i == 1
        @user.owner!
    else
        @user.player!
    end
```

I also added some validations to my user model to ensure that a user has a role:

```
validates :role, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ["player", "owner", "admin"] }
```

Now last thing to be careful about is that a user could edit the html and put "admin" as the option value and try to sign up as an admin. So you want to restrict this in the users_controller in the create method:

```
if !@user.admin? && @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Welcome, #{@user.username}!"
    session[:user_id] = @user.id

    redirect_accordingly(@user)
else
    flash[:alert] = "Some of the info you provided needs tweaking."
    render :new
end
```

Hope that makes sense! Let me know if that didn't work or something doesn't make sense. Happy coding!

Comment: I actually really like this approach and I'm going to try it out when I get home later. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Just note that you need at least Rails 4.1 to use enum. It's a new recent feature. And with this role as an enum, you can do authorization using the Pundit Gem: https://github.com/elabs/pundit